# What is wrong with ScriptManager?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have been having a problem with my ASP.NET web forms page unobtrusive validation NOT working on customer site. Works, however, for me in my VS 2012. Aside from the fact that validation does not work (that is, the requiredfield validation is ignored and empty fields do not stop from submitting the form) another manifestation is the following. When I run the page in IE 11 Developer Tools (DT) -> Network, ScriptResource.axd is NOT loading. That is, in the DT there are 3 lines with ScriptResource.axd?d..... that have Method GET but Result 404 (meaning not loaded, for whatever reasons).

I found what is causing the problem on the customer site. The ASP.NET page has the following section:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="sm1" runat="server">
    <Scripts>
       <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery"/>
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

When I remove/delete the above section from the .aspx file the Validation works and the IE11 Developer Tools does not have the lines ScriptResource.axd.

My question is, can you think of why removing the above section resolves the problem on customer site? What - if any - negative effects could be if I permanently remove this section?

Comment: I'd first try to find out the difference between customer's site and your local copy. Are you using the same web.config? What about ScriptMode? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.scriptmode(v=vs.110).aspx Is the IIS set up correctly? (Are you using the same IIS version?)

Comment: @rocky  It appears that IIS is set up correctly; the same IIS version as I have. But what I am trying to understand is, what is the benefit of the ScriptManage code (posted above)?  What would be lost if I permanently remove this section?

Comment: ScriptReference is an ASP.NET way of registering scripts. The benefit is e.g. that you can include scripts that are embedded as a resource in an assembly. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptreference(v=vs.110).aspx The problem might be that on production machine the jQuery is registered twice (once using ScriptReference and once as a classic <script> tag). If this is the case it's safe to remove the ScriptReference. Can you check what is actually being rendered?

Comment: @rocky  It appeared that what is being rendered didn't change when I had and when removed the ScriptManager section.  Thank you for additional information and for the link. You could be right that something was being registered twice.  My goal is to find a way to duplicate this "bad" behavior on my PC. If I can do it, then I know for sure how to prevent the problem in the future.

Comment: @rocky Your link is very helpful. However, I am confused about the following.  The "standard" VS 2012 ASP.NET web forms include the following ScriptReference (among others):
    <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
The above code has both the Path and Assembly attributes. But the msdn page says (in Remarks) "To register a static script file, set the Path property of the ScriptReference object to the relative location of the file." and the following paragraph: (in next comment):

Comment: "To register a script file that is embedded as a resource in an assembly, set the Assembly property to the name of the assembly that contains the file. Then set the Name property to the name of the .js file that is embedded in the assembly. In that case, the script file must be embedded, not linked."
Why then the "standard" VS 2012 reference has both Assembly and Path?

Comment: Don't know but I think it's not necessary to have both defined. Maybe it's because some differences between webapplication and website. Really don't know.

Comment: Anyway, can you check network tab in your dev console (e.g. firebug) to see whether there are the same requests when it's registered and when not?

Comment: @rocky  Thank you.  I will follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using `UpdatePanel`s or some other Microsoft Ajax Extension (like the AjaxControlToolkit) then there is no harm in removing the `ScriptManager`.

If you plan to use UpdatePanels in the future, then you could try removing only the `Scripts` tag. And include your Jquery file with a traditional HTML script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-(your version).min.js"></script>
```

Comment: cpacheco, I do not use UpdatePanel and I do have Jquery files in the Head section of the page (just as you wrote in your example). And I do not use MS Ajax Extensions.  So I will remove this section.
Thank you very much.